Tuning IIS 10 Services
I have a Server 2019 instance running Revit Server 2022/2024. Revit is architectural design software - a client runs on the workstation, the drawings/models are stored server-side and the data is served up using an IIS site/service. The client pulls down a copy of the model locally, and as the architect is working on the model, it occasionally syncs up with the server allowing for multiple architects to work simultaneously on the same model(s).
I'm by no means a Revit or IIS expert, I basically followed the AutoDesk guides to get Server 2019 and Revit Server(s) set up. However, on the LAN, model load times can be up to 60 minutes. AutoDesk support is basically useless in helping us get things optimized server-side.
So:

Is there a way to get performance data out of IIS so that I can see in fine-grained detail what exactly is taking so long when someone initiates loading a model?

Is there an authoritative source I can reference to learn how to troubleshoot and tune IIS-related performance issues? I know Microsoft has one here, but if there are better sources I'd like to know them.



Having a thorough understanding of the specific areas you want to optimize is imperative for effective performance tuning. If AutoDesk support is unable to provide further assistance, seeking help from others might not be advantageous. The Microsoft guide is very specific to typical web apps, not really applicable to vendor products like Revit.

Right. Hence question #1, I don't know which part of this is taking a long time. There's very little resource usage on both the client and server sides. Someone must know how to interrogate IIS to find out which part(s) if any are hung up.

Enabling Failed Request Tracing could be a potential solution to investigate the issue further. However, it is worth noting that this may not provide significant insights if the time consumption is primarily caused by Revit components. In such cases, it is only feasible to consult the vendor who has a better understanding of the internals of these components.
